# Content of UIScrollView has offset below Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, offset, statusbar

I have a UIScrollView which contains a UIView, that in turn has an UIImageView and several UIButtons in it.
The problem I have is that the image is displayed about 20 px underneath my navigation bar.

People who seem to have similar problems had solutions like setting

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or just hide the status bar

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

However, both solutions don't work for me. The first one sets the contents too high and adds the 20px space at the bottom instead. The second one hides the status bar , but the offset still remains.

[image: problem]

Since I have a lot of the code from [this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518) and I have no idea where exactly in my code the problem lies, [this is the link to code on github](https://github.com/frederike/NZTravellerApp/blob/master/NZTravellerApp/CustomScrollViewController.m).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what is going on. Thanks for posting the link to your app.

The issue is this following code:

```
if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}
```

It turns out the `contentsFrame.size.height` is in fact less than `bounds.Size.height` when the map is first displayed. So your code is centering the image vertically. That's why you see that offset at the top. 17.279 pixels to be exact.

I've been playing around with your app (which seem very interesting btw) and I believe that you can get rid of the two calls to `centerScrollViewContents` altogether and it will work just as you expected.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem! I'm still a bit confused why, if the scroll view is larger than the contents, I don't see a white space at the top AND at the bottom, because that's what I thought the method would do in that case. But I removed it now and it's working as I want it to!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's going on as I'm not that familiar with the code but I'm glad I was able to help. Also, I'm not sure if this is appropriate, but let me know if you want/need contributors for your project. It looks interesting and I'm sure I could help you out. Cheers.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I only saw your comment now! I'm always looking to improve, so contributions from people with more experience than me are always appreciated! I'm also relatively new to github, so I'm not sure what the best way to have someone contribute is. In the readme file are a couple of things I still want to work on / need help with. I would really appreciate some more input!

Comment: I forgot to tag my previous comment with your name, so I'm not sure you got a notification @LuisCien

Comment: Hi @freda42. Yes I got the notification last time but was busy and couldn't reply right away. I've seen the readme file and there are things that I can definitely help you with. Let me know if there's any particular one you want me to do or I'll just fork the project and choose one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was the right solution, all the others failed!

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is the one from @LuisCien

I'm adding here that I have found it useful when using UIScrollView with a MPMediaPickerController, so:

```
- (void)fixViewFrameBoundSize {
     CGRect contentsFrame = self.view.frame;
     CGSize boundsSize = self.view.bounds.size;
     if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
         contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
     } else {
         contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
     }
     [self.view setFrame:contentsFrame];
}
```

and

```
- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self fixViewFrameBoundSize];
    });
}];
```

}

and the same for the selected items callback:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{

                             //LP : get item url and play

                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [self fixViewFrameBoundSize];
                             });

                             MPMediaItem *item = [collection representativeItem];
```

This solution works well when you have a XIB with a UIView, and you transform it in a UISCrollView as follows:

```
- (void)scrollViewMakeScrollable {
       CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+44.0);
       [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setContentSize:scrollableSize];
       [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
       [((UIScrollView*)self.view) setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
       self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

}

So normally when you are doing like

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];

      [self scrollViewMakeScrollable];
```